# Moving from TFS2013 to tfs 2015

Tags: tfs, move, tfs-2015

We are using TFS2013 on windows server 2008R2 with sql server 2012. Now we want to move this to TFS2015... with connection to sql server 2014 (WINDOWS SERVER 2012..diff machine)...any pointers in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently upgraded our SQL server using this using [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2014/05/15/migrating-team-foundation-server-databases/) as a guide. It's spot on but missing one step, at the very end before you start TFS back up you need to start IIS.

I would recommend first doing the upgrade for TFS then migrate the databases.

Based on the information [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d73ec567-77b3-4187-a6f7-189795c69452/restoring-a-backup-of-a-sql-server-2014-db-into-a-sql-server-2012-instance?forum=sqldatabaseengine) you should be fine restoring your backups from 2012 to 2014. Just verified that we did exactly that, moved from 2012 to 2014.

Comment: It's talking about backup and restore database. In my case, old database is in sql server 2012 and new one is supposed to be in 2014..will this work?

Comment: are you just planning on updating the SQL server or are you moving to a new SQL server?

Comment: Thanks, New sql server

Comment: It's supposed to work. Make sure you have full backup before migration. You can also review this article:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664027/Migrate-Team-Foundation-Server-s-SQL-Server-to-ano

Comment: aah...after getting 2 negative..i realize that i am going from 2012 to 2014 and not the other-way...so backup restore shud work...thanks